# Calculate real distances based on OSM/Google roads between many points ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance, network

In ArcGIS I've two shapefiles with many points called "source" with hundreds of points, and another called "destinations". Based on the roads data of OSM/Google/other, I'd like to calculate the real distances between each point of the couple source-destination.

I've done some searchig, but I found only a solution for linear distances (tool Point distance or similar) o using network analysis but for one point at time.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to include what you have tried and what error you encountered.

Comment: I'v tried nothing, I haven't find a tool to do what I'm looking for.

Comment: A google on "arcgis distance pairs" returns quite a number of pages, enough of them GIS SE that this appears to be duplicate. It **is** a requirement to  perform basic research before asking a question.

Comment: I've done a "basic search", but you find only a solution for linear distances (tool Point distance or similar) o using network analysis but for one point at time.

Comment: Then **edit the question** to specify what you have searched, and how it failed to meet your requirements.  At that point you'll be closer to an answerable question.